# Managing display of articles promoted to front page

Tags: theming, nodes

How do we manage the way that blog items that are promoted to the front page are displayed?
Currently using Bootstrap theme, we promote some of our articles, these are displayed in a scroller, but just showing one article at a time. 
How would I manage this so that the scroller showed 3 articles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to yoursite/admin/config/system/site-information
2. Change the Number of posts on front page to 3 or whatever you want.

Please note your allow to display up to 30 post, however if you want to show more then 30 than i suggest to use [View module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), to create page of your article list

Comment: Fantastic. 
When it was just set to 1 the items scrolled across. Now there are 3 the items are listed underneath each other. 
What would the best way to get 3 items scrolling next to each other. (I suspect that this is a new view module)

Comment: You can use CSS or View module and view horizontal.